# polygons on googlemaps api from mysqldb

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I have series of lat and lon of every vertex in MySQL db and every vertex of polygon has the same number of ORIG_FID based on polygon then I have parsed them with PHP to XML format  now how I can loop through my MySQL data on java script to show the polygons on google map automatically.

I am confused on making code of java script code ; that how I can loop through these lat and lon to take those  number of lat and lon which have the same oriq_fid.

```
 <markers>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="1" lat="34.5127" lng="69.3182"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="2" lat="34.5128" lng="69.3174"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="3" lat="34.5134" lng="69.3175"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="4" lat="34.5133" lng="69.3183"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="5" lat="34.5127" lng="69.3182"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="6" lat="34.5145" lng="69.3099"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="7" lat="34.5144" lng="69.3104"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="8" lat="34.5139" lng="69.3104"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="9" lat="34.514" lng="69.3099"/>
<marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="10" lat="34.5145" lng="69.3099"/>
</markers>
```

Comment: Hello. You need to re-write your question in clear English, with appropriate phrasing, punctuation and syntax. Otherwise you may not be able to ask questions in Stack Overflow (at least in the English version).

Comment: Write a PHP code that generates valid [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) file and later load this GeoJSON to Google Maps as shown in the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data

Comment: i apologize  @J.C.Rocamonde but i am living in Afghanistan  and u maybe know the conditions of Afghanistan and about  6 months ago i have started studying ENGLISH and computer_science  with my self and before that i did'nt know about abc of English and computer and this post was my first post in my life after this i well use clear English .Thank you!

Comment: @khantaeb it is not about apologising, I do not feel offended if you make a grammar mistake. I it so people can understand your question clearly and help you better.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde my question is i have series of lat and lon of vertex of polygon and every polygon vertex   lat and lon have orig_fid  which link  the polygonwith lat and lon  now how can i loop throw these lat and lon to show them on google map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. parse the XML

```
var xml = parseXml(xmlStr);
```

2. retrieve the coordinates for each FID

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
  var lat = markers[i].getAttribute('lat');
  var lng = markers[i].getAttribute('lng');
  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var FID = markers[i].getAttribute('ORIG_FID');
  if (!paths[FID])
    paths[FID] = [];
  paths[FID].push(pt);
}
```

3. build a polygon for each path

```
for (var path in paths) {
  if (paths.hasOwnProperty(path)) {
    path = paths[path];

    // Construct the polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: path,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4uxvp9Lf/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}
var xmlStr = '<markers><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="1" lat="34.5127" lng="69.3182"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="2" lat="34.5128" lng="69.3174"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="3" lat="34.5134" lng="69.3175"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="4" lat="34.5133" lng="69.3183"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="1" OBJECTID="5" lat="34.5127" lng="69.3182"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="6" lat="34.5145" lng="69.3099"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="7" lat="34.5144" lng="69.3104"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="8" lat="34.5139" lng="69.3104"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="9" lat="34.514" lng="69.3099"/><marker title="hi" ORIG_FID="2" OBJECTID="10" lat="34.5145" lng="69.3099"/></markers>'
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  var infoWindow;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {
        lat: 24.886,
        lng: -70.268
      },
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
    var xml = parseXml(xmlStr);
    var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    var path = [];
    var paths = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var lat = markers[i].getAttribute('lat');
      var lng = markers[i].getAttribute('lng');
      var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var FID = markers[i].getAttribute('ORIG_FID');
      if (!paths[FID])
        paths[FID] = [];
      paths[FID].push(pt);
      bounds.extend(pt);
    }
    for (var path in paths) {
      if (paths.hasOwnProperty(path)) {
        path = paths[path];

        // Construct the polygon.
        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: path,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        polygon.setMap(map);
        // Add a listener for the click event.
        polygon.addListener('click', showArrays);
      }
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);



    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  }

  /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
  function showArrays(event) {
    // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
    // MVCArray of LatLngs.
    var vertices = this.getPath();

    var contentString = '<b>Polygon</b><br>' +
      'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
      '<br>';

    // Iterate over the vertices.
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
      var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
      contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
        xy.lng();
    }

    // Replace the info window's content and position.
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your  answer now how i can use XML data from URL not manually from string